# spring jpa transaction number of queries

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-transactions

We are using Spring + JPA + Hibernate + MYSQL for our project. Using EHCache, query cache and c3p0 as well.

At one point in code, we start a new transaction for every request.

Just before leaving the method which created the transaction, I would like to get the
number of queries which hit the database in the current transaction.

Please do guide me on how to get this information.

Comment: you can start by reading about interceptors and aop

Answer (score 1):

You will need to wrap the JDBC classes (take a look at [P6SPY](http://sourceforge.net/projects/p6spy/)). You can also achieve something similar by writing an around aspect - you will need to use aspectj as spring aop will not be able to apply aspects to classes that are not beans.

Once you have the ability to add additional logic on each database call you can then create an  implementation that uses thread locals to hold counts for each transaction separately.

Use the spring [transaction syncronization](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionSynchronization.html)  support to reset / log the statistics when the transaction completes.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate have support for [statistics](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-optional-statistics) and check [this](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t19807.html) for usage. Check `org.hibernate.stat.QueryStatistics.getExecutionCount()`. But this gives count of all queries executed until that point, so you need to get the difference between count before method execution and after execution. Also you need to make sure that no other transaction(for example quartz scheduled jobs) is performing operation on db to get accurate count.

Comment: Cannot use this as its a multi-threaded system, and we have multiple requests executing most of the time